# What is the generating function for $c(n,k)$?

Tags: stirling-numbers

I was reading "The Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis" by John Riordan. Let $c(n,k)$ denote the signless Stirling number of the first kind.

He asks, how many permutations there are with $k$ cycles, regardless of lengths, and then gives ([link](http://books.google.com/books?id=zWgIPlds29UC&lpg=PA71&vq=signless%20Stirling&pg=PA70#v=snippet&q=signless%20Stirling&f=false) to Google books) the computation:
$$
\begin{align*}
\exp uc(t) &=\exp t(u+u^2/2+u^3/3+\cdots)\\
&=\exp t\log(1-u)^{-1}\\
&=(1-u)^{-t}\\
&= 1+\sum_1^\infty t(t+1)\cdots(t+n-1)\frac{u^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
$$
And so $c_n(t)=t(t+1)\cdots(t+n-1)$ is the generating function of the signless Stirling numbers. I understand all the equalities, but I don't get how he arrives at the result. Why does he start out by looking at $\exp uc(t)$? What's the $u$ for? Can someone please break it down? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $\exp uC(t)$ is not an exponential of $uC(t)$, rather it is a notation for the following generating function
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n) \frac{u^n}{n!}
$$
where $C_n$ is a cycle indicator, also related to the [Bell polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials). As explained on the linked wiki page, as in the book you are reading, this generating function is, in fact, as exponential of another series:
$$
    \exp\left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{u^m}{m} t_m \right)
$$

$C_n(t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_n)$ is a cycle indicator, meaning that coefficient by $t_1^{m_1} t_2^{m_2} \cdots t_n^{m_n}$ gives the number of permutations with $m_1$ cycles of length 1, $m_2$ cycles of length 2, and so on. As we are interested in the number of permutations with $k$ cycles, irrespective of their length, the generating function for such a number in a permutation of $S_n$ is 
$$
    c_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n t^k \sum_{m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_n=k} C\left(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\right) = C_n(t,t,\ldots,t)
$$
Thus
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(t) \frac{u^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(t,t,\ldots,t) \frac{u^n}{n!} = \exp\left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{u^m}{m!}t \right) = \exp\left(-t \log(1-u)\right) = (1-u)^{-t}
$$
Now the latter, by the generalized binomial theorem is
$$
   \left(1-u\right)^{-t} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{-t}{m} (-u)^m = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)(-t-1)\cdots (-t-m-1)}{m!} (-1)^m u^m = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(t)_m}{m!} u^m 
$$
where $(t)_m$ denotes the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: Thank you Sasha, this definitely clears it up for me.